# Как сделать, чтобы меню плавно выезжало справа налево?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я первый раз использовал js,поэтому не могу понять, как это сделать. С кликом получилось, а вот с плавным выездом нет. И да, это мой первый раз использования адаптивного меню.

Вот мой код:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("burger").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.openmenu')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("burger-menu-item");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }


}
```

```css
.openmenu {
  top: 25px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 320px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openmenu:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.7);
}

.burgermenu {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.burger-menu-item {
  width: 165px;
  height: 250px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #F2785C;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 5;
  left: 225px;
  top: 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.burger-menu-item a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-family: 'Red Hat Text';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 21px;
}

.burger-menu-item a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(207, 108, 108)
}

.show {
  display: block;
}

.close-menu {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #F2785C;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="burgermenu">
  <img src="./img/eva_menu-outline.svg" alt="lineone" onclick="myFunction()" class="openmenu">

  <div id="burger" class="burger-menu-item">
    <button class="close-menu">×</button>
    <a href="#preview">How It Works</a>
    <a href="#steps">Plan Your Trip</a>
    <a href="#destinations">Destinations</a>
    <a href="#stories">Travel Stories</a>
    <a href="#links">Account</a>
    <a href="#media">Social Media</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Свойство display: none/block нельзя изменить плавно, потому что у него нет промежуточных состояний. Используйте opacity (появление/исчезновение), transform: translateX (перемещение слева направо и обратно) и transition для плавности этих действий.

Answer (score 1):

Пример

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menu.classList.toggle('is-open')
})
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: translateX(150%);
  transition: transform .3s ease;
}

.menu.is-open {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">Menu</div>
<button>btn</button>
```